# Content not displayed in Ionic

Tags: android, mobile, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an app that displays my blog posts in news feed.I  am using ionic for it.My problem is that the titles of posts are not displayed on the html page while I can access them in console window.I am unable to understand the reason for this.Please help me to fix the problem.
 The code of my html page is

```
<ion-view view-title="TheGeekInn" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Geek</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="story in stories">
        {{story.title}}
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and the code for controller is

```
  .controller('homeCtrl',function($http,$scope){
  $scope.stories=[];
  $http.get('http://www.thegeekinn.in/category/technical/?json=1').success(function(response){
  angular.forEach(response.posts,function(post){
    $scope.stories.push(post.title);
    console.log(post.title);
          });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked. Unfortunately I don't know the why. Hope this helps.

```
$http.get('http://www.thegeekinn.in/category/technical/?json=1').success(function(response){
            $scope.stories=response.posts;
        });
```